# Emulate a BLE in peripheral ( mimic temp sensor) in ubuntu using BLE dongle

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Need guidance on how a BLE dongle connected to my ubuntu can be used as a BLE peripheral in order to mimic a BLE temp sensor. Using this, I should be able to push out pre-defined temp data via BLE dongle in peripheral mode.

Comment: Which BLE dongle ? Maybe buy a nRF51 dongle and program it, there are some tutorial on Nordic website to create custom and/or generic services and characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am using a CSR BLE dongle that I had got for the Raspberry pi.   Mini Bluetooth CSR 4.0 USB Dongle Adapter . Will all dongles not be able to switch themselves to peripheral mode using the hci commands?

Comment: You can use bleno for example.

Comment: Well yes I guess you can pretty easily have it advertising but if you want some services and characteristic you'll need to program a bit.

Comment: Planning to order a Bluefruit LE friend (NRF51822) [link]https://www.adafruit.com/product/2267 [link]. Specs say that it woukd support UART mode to make the required configuration. @TimF Am curious to know on the extent of programming and the kind that would be required to get the  service & characteristics working . This would enable to get any  dongle to be used as a peripheral.

Comment: Well it depends on your background in C and BLE but it's pretty simple since the tutorial is complete and the source code is provided, you just have to extend it. You can also do that on a nRF52 dev kit, it's more recent and maybe better for programing. You can use free tools such as Eclipse and gcc as well as nRF Go Studio